# image to follow scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, cursor

I am not sure where to start.  I am looking for the best way to have an image that will follow a browser scrollbar down a webpage or across the bottom of a webpage page.  If, for example you have scrolled halfway down a webpage page, an image(arrow) will point to the scrollbar. As you travel down or across the page, the image will travel as well.  I am not looking for scripts that have an image following a cursor since this doesn't take into account that a user might be using scroll wheel on a mouse, in which case, the cursor is not moving even though the page is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, I want the arrow to point to the position bar that is within the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position: fixed` css so the element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Comment: that makes absolutely no sense, because then you fix the position to a certein point and don't have it at the scroll position of the scroll bar

Comment: he said that arrow have to point the scrollbar, not the bar inside the scrollbar! I answer to what he askd!

Answer (score 0):

The information about how the browser presents the scrollbar, if it even has one, which side of the window it is on, or how it is rendered **is not available** to the web page.

However, you could do a decent job of guessing with some math.

Take the `document scroll position / document height * display port height` and that will give you rough pixel count of where the scroll bar is from the top of the screen.

Make your HTML element `position: fixed;` and set the `top: 123px` to match the calculation above.  Refresh this on the Scroll event.

You will need to google for the specific JavaScript commands to make this happen, but in concept, it should get you pretty close.

---

If you want to be more accurate, keep in mind that the scroll bar size is typically going to be `(display port height / document height) * display port height`.  If you subtract this value from the range of motion of your arrow, and add half of this value to the `top` pixel value of your arrow, it should typically point to the middle of the scroll bar.